# What should Surl and Furl contains in PayU - payemnt gateway?

Tags: java, android, payment, payumoney, payu

I am new to Stackoverflow.

I have doubt in Payu payment gateway can we call our own activity instead of Surl and Furl.
If the above ans is No then,
How to create surl and furl I'm creating whole application on my own so ,
i dont have any knowledge of web development .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surl and Furl mean Success URL and Failure URL respectively.
>   Basically, Surl and Furl are the return URL

The `Success URLS` will get invoked when a Payment is successful

`Failure URL` will get invoked when the payment is a Failure

You need to create your own HTML pages and add the URL in your code

You can see the doc related to this in the [link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/4.-Server-Side) and the sample code is also available.

Comment: Thanks for the Above details,@Rakshit Nawani

Comment: Another question arises , how to compare Merchant post data with payU post data after transaction.plz help me in this also. @Rakshit

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully, all the implementation are added to it. If my answer helped you do upvote and accept my answer. Thanks in advence